# Why is R giving a bad result of addition?

Tags: r

I can't seem to do a comparison with a sum of numbers and get the right answer (lines alternate between my input and R output):

> (.6 + .3 + .1) == 1
>
> [1] FALSE
>
> (.6 + .3 + .1)
>
> [1] 1
>
> 1
>
> [1] 1

I've tried with and without parenthesis, tried comparing to 1.0, tried using as.numeric, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've fallen into the "Floating Point Trap." See the first chapter of the R Inferno:  http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

You want to test floating point numbers with `all.equal` instead, like this:

```
> all.equal(.6+.3+.1, 1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks that helps!. BTW people should know that all.equal does NOT return FALSE when false. So to do the comparison you need to wrap isTRUE around all.equal. A long way to go just to compare 2 numbers.

Answer (score 9):

It is floating point rounding.  You get

```
> round(.6 + .3 + .1, digits=16) == 1
[1] FALSE
> round(.6 + .3 + .1, digits=15) == 1
[1] TRUE
> (.6 + .3 + .1) - 1
[1] -1.11022302462516e-16
```